# Overdispersion in a beta regression? (DHARMa package)

Tags: r, mixed-model, overdispersion, beta-regression, glmmtmb

I'm trying to run a beta regression to predict my dependent variable Consistency, which has values between 0 and 1.
Here is the distribution of Consistency values in my dataset:
[image: Histogram of consistency]

I originally tried linear mixed models with different transformations, but none of them seemed satisfactory (none of the Q-Q plots looked good), so I decided to try a beta regression, using the following command:

```
l_cons <- glmmTMB(as.formula(paste(var_predicted, ' ~ ', paste(effets_model, collapse = ' + '), '+ ', nom_random, sep = '')), data = d, family=beta_family())
```

(the model is quite massive with a huge number of predictor variables and interactions, hence this construction rather than adding each predictor variable manually).

Now, I wanted to test if overdispersion might be a problem. First of all, by calling

```
summary(l_cons)
```

I get

```
 Data: d

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 -6861.3  -6465.1   3499.7  -6999.3     2235 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Sujet  (Intercept) 0.04931  0.2221  
Number of obs: 2304, groups:  Sujet, 72

Dispersion parameter for beta family (): 26.5
```

Moreover by calling (from the DHARMa package):

```
simulateResiduals(l_cons, plot = T)
```

I get the following output:
[image: output of simulateResiduals()]
as well as

```
testDispersion(simulateResiduals(l_cons, plot = T))
```

with the following output:
[image]
Can somebody explain to me what this means? Does it mean that the distribution of my data is altogether unfit for a beta regression? Are there some transformations that should be done? If the conclusion from this information is that there is indeed overdispersion, what does that mean exactly?